# Difference between Record and Packed Record

Tags: delphi, record

I searched and found out that Packed Record in Delphi uses less space. But why to use Record? Are there any **things** that a Record can do and Packed Record cannot?

```
TCourse = Packed Record
CId: String;                   
CName: String;
CDuration: string;
end;
```

Comment: one reason -> alignment. Performance will go down if data is not aligned...

Comment: Generally you want to do the exact opposite. Never pack structures because that destroys alignment.

Comment: I think the reason for `packed` is mainly historical -  it used to be commonplace to store data on disk as a 'file of record' for file-system databases, and with old, tiny hard disks, `packed` could signicantly save diskspace and improve reading speed.

Comment: Another use for packed is if you want to overlay a binary structure with an ordered structure.